# I got errors with large dataset clustermap

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn

I'm trying to create a clustermap for a large dataset using the command line :

```
sns.clustermap(dataset)
```

and visualize it using :

```
plt.show()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\RNA_expression.py", line 44, in <module>

    sns.clustermap(exp)

  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 1406, in clustermap
    return plotter.plot(metric=metric, method=method,

  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 1219, in plot

    self.plot_dendrograms(row_cluster, col_cluster, metric, method,
  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 1074, in plot_dendrograms

    self.dendrogram_col = dendrogram(
  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 3653, in _dendrogram_calculate_info

    _dendrogram_calculate_info(
  [Previous line repeated 237 more times]

  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 3620, in _dendrogram_calculate_info
    _dendrogram_calculate_info(
  
  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 3653, in _dendrogram_calculate_info
    _dendrogram_calculate_info(
  [Previous line repeated 646 more times]

  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 3620, in _dendrogram_calculate_info
    _dendrogram_calculate_info(

  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 3550, in _dendrogram_calculate_info
    _append_singleton_leaf_node(Z, p, n, level, lvs, ivl,

  File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\pythonProject1-6HarIJ1S\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 3425, in _append_singleton_leaf_node
    ivl.append(str(int(i)))

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

I tried resolving it by increasing the recursion limit :

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

But then I got this line :
Process finished with exit code -107341571 (0xC00000FD)

Do you have any other solution that I can try to get my clustermap?

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for your reply! I'm using the latest version of seaborn (0.11.2). And i'm trying to run it again with a smallest subset but it's taking a lot of time. I'll let you know once I get the results

Comment: The error happens in scipy, so upgrading that library might also be useful.  According to https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1152 you can simulate the error with something like  `dataset = (rng.uniform(size=(6597, 686)) < .02).astype(int)`.  The issue also explains that a clustermap of so many rows/columns, even if it doesn't crash, would generate an extremely messy tree.

Comment: Related scipy issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7271

Comment: Okay I see! Thank you so much for your suggestions and for editing my question. I'll try to figure it out and if I find a solution that works for me, I'll post it here.